# How to query against array in Cosmos using sql?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

This is my data where I want to get `stockNumber` if `operationId` in `lineItems` is occurring more than once.

i.e., as an output, my query should return `2002762240` out of these 2 records because it has same operationId twice.

Doc-1

```
{
  "stockNumber": "2002762240",
  "lineItems": [
    {
      "operationId": 8424759,
      "partLineId": null
    },
    {
      "operationId": 8424759,
      "partLineId": 0
    }
  ],
  "paymentItems": [
    {
      "subletDetails": [
        {
          "operationId": 8424759
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Doc-2

```
{
  "stockNumber": "2002762241",
  "lineItems": [
    {
      "operationId": 8424760,
      "partLineId": 0
    }
  ],
  "paymentItems": [
    {
      "subletDetails": [
        {
          "operationId": 8424760
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Approach-1: This gives me records which also exists in `paymentItems`. I only care for `lineItems`

```
SELECT top 100
  c.stockNumber AS stockNumber
FROM c
WHERE ARRAY_LENGTH(ARRAY(SELECT VALUE l.operationId FROM l IN c.lineItems GROUP BY l.operationId)) > 1
```

Approach-2: Throws `BadRequest` error

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.stockNumber 
FROM c JOIN l IN c.lineItems 
GROUP BY l.operationId 
HAVING COUNT(1) > 1
```

Approach-3: Throws `BadRequest` error

```
SELECT top 100
  c.stockNumber AS stockNumber
FROM c
WHERE ARRAY_LENGTH(c.lineItems) > 0
and EXISTS (
    select l.operationId from l in c.lineItems GROUP BY l.operationId 
HAVING COUNT(1) > 1
)
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error was caused by using `HAVING` in the query. Cosmos doesn't support the `HAVING` clause, so it is better to use the `WHERE` clause, as shown in the code below.

Use the following query to get `stockNumber` where `operationId` in `lineItems` occurs more than once.

```sql
SELECT 
    result.stockNumber
FROM (
    SELECT 
        c.stockNumber AS stockNumber,
        l.operationId AS operationId,
        COUNT(1) AS operationIdCount
    FROM c
    JOIN l IN c.lineItems
    GROUP BY c.stockNumber, l.operationId
) AS result
WHERE result.operationIdCount > 1
```

**Output:**

```js
[
    {
        "stockNumber": "2002762240"
    }
]
```

Comment: this will time out for larger records (> 10,000 or so) but I got the idea. Thank you